# How to create two boxplots in the same graph?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I've created a boxplot that looks like this:

[image]

and i used this data to get there:

[image]

I now have to filter the data to only include Low and High fire_severity and make separate boxplots of ecozone (x-axis) and proportion (y-axis) by levels of fire_severity. I need to end up with boxplots that look like this:

[image]

This is the code i have so far but it doesn't seem to be working:

```
    table_long4 %>% filter(fire_severity == "Low", fire_severity == "High") %>%
  ggplot(table_long4, aes(x = cover_type, y = proportion, fill = ecozone)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, outlier.size = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"), name = "") +
  labs(y = "Proportion of ground cover", x = "Cover Type") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),
        legend.position = "top",
        legend.direction = "horizontal",
        legend.title = element_blank(),
        legend.justification = "left",
        legend.key.size = unit(0.6, "cm")) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "green", "blue"), name = "") +
    facet_wrap(~ Low + High)
```

Comment: Use `facet_wrap()`. See `?facet_wrap()` for details as to how.

Comment: Try `facet_wrap(~ fire_severity)` instead of `facet_wrap(~ Low + High)`, i.e. use the name of the variable you want to facet by.